# SASS child selector not finding its target

Tags: angular, sass

OK so I have the following HTML (via angular 6)

```
<mat-tab-group class="mat-tab-group is-third-party">
<mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header">
```

I then have the following SASS that I am trying to get working

```
 mat-tab-group {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100%;
      display: inherit; 

      &.is-third-party {
           background-color: blue;

           mat-tab-header {
                display: none !important;
           }
      }
```

Everything work as far as down to isThirdParty (I get my blue background which I've added to see what the heck is going on)

I've tried all sorts of combinations to get mat-tab-header to be hit but its not having it. I've tried . for the class name, the child selector > and whatever I do I don't get the mat-tab-header being hit and hence hidden.

I've only dabbled in SASS, can somebody see what I am doing wrong please?
UPDATE: See my image below, bit more bloat in the html but you can see the HTML looks ok for this SASS?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the header is not hidden?

Comment: I don't get the mat-tab-header being hit and hence hidden

Comment: Correct it is still visible. Any styling I add does not take affect for mat-tab-header

Comment: The code looks fine to me, are you 100% sure that the header you are seeing is inside of `mat-tab-group.is-third-party`?

Comment: Try to add before  mat-tab-header : & > .mat-tab-header. And just a note,

Comment: dAxx not sure that comment was finished but I have & > mat-tab-header {      which still isn't working. You seem to have the : also but that doesn't seem to be valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your styles don't apply to the Angular Material components nested in your Angular component because of Angular's [style scoping feature](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope). By default component styles are not inherited by any components nested within your component's template.

You have the following options to define styles that apply to other components nested within a component (like your Angular Material components):

- Add the styles to your global styles.scss file
- Keep the styles in your component and turn off *view encapsulation* for this component.
- Keep the styles in your component and use a **deprecated** shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force styles to apply to all the child elements. (see original answer below)

---

#### Disabling View Encapsulation

Disable *view encapsulation* on your components that use Angular Material components.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomp',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

> *ViewEncapsulation.None* means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.
>   [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

If you turn off view encapsulation make sure to target only the html element you realy want, because the styles defined for this component now apply to your whole Angular app (not just the one component). (e.g. add a custom *class* or *id* to your element)

I've found that when disabling *view encapsulation* you might also have to use `!important` in your CSS to overwrite existing Angular Material styles, while it wasn't always needed with `::ng-deep`.

---

#### Using `::ng-deep`

Put `::ng-deep` in front of your your parent selector.

> Note that `::ng-deep` is currently [**deprecated**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

```css
::ng-deep mat-tab-group {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: inherit; 

  &.is-third-party {
       background-color: blue;

       mat-tab-header {
            display: none !important;
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: that works but is soon to be deprecated. Can you explain why that works please so as to maybe highlight another way around the problem as I'm still not fully understanding why the 2 parent classes are fine but not the third...

Comment: I'm not sure myself why this is needed here, as it should be only needed to target HTML elements in child components. I'd guess it has something to do with the way Angular Material works...

Comment: right ok that gave me the clue I needed.... that class is part of the html rendered by an angular material component. If I put that CSS into the styles.scss at the parent level it works. I'd like to be able to avoid doing that really. Is there a way?

Comment: An alternative should be to disable view encapsulation on your component: @Component({ encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None }). You then have to make sure to target only the mat-tab-header you realy want, and not any other ones in child components. Probably add a custom class to it. I haven't tested this yet but will try it out soon, as I'm dealing with the same problem.

Comment: I tested the 'disable vie encapsulation' method in my project and it works for me. Updated my answer.

Comment: Do you want to add this as an answer and I'' mark it up

Answer (score 0):

In your sass you have

```
mat-tab-group {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: inherit; 

  &.is-third-party {
       background-color: blue;

       mat-tab-header {
            display: none !important;
       }
  }
```

it should be (notice the "." before the mat-tab-group)

```
.mat-tab-group {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: inherit; 

  &.is-third-party {
       background-color: blue;

       mat-tab-header {
            display: none !important;
       }
  }
```

Comment: thats not working. NOTE: the yellow and blue backgrounds are being displayed so as my code is now I get that far, it is the mat-tab-header query that isn't working

Comment: Also .mat-tab-header {  display: none !important;  }

Comment: tried .mat-tab-header also. See my edited question for image of my html

Comment: @robertoLL The problem here isn't specificity rather Angular's View Encapsulation as the chosen answer states